# Which of these is a better method for summing up rows and creating a plot (melt and cast, or tapply and creating a new data frame)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

**head(data)**

```
       year Emissions
114470 1999      7.38
114472 1999      2.78
114477 1999     11.76
114479 1999      3.50
114481 1999      1.32
114486 1999      5.58
```

This is massive data set with 4 years (1999, 2002, 2005, and 2008). I want to compare the total emissions in each year in a plot. Which of the two methods below is better (better = more applicable to other problems)? In both I make a plot after with ggplot2, that's why I create the df in the first way.

**first way**

```
  sums <- tapply(data$Emissions, data$year, sum)
  df <- data.frame(year = names(sums), pollution = sums, row.names = NULL)
```

**second way**

```
  melted_data <- melt(data, id.vars = c("year"))
  df2 <- dcast(melted_data, year ~ variable, sum)
```

They both have the same output. df == df2 returns TRUE

Comment: do both produce your desired result?  If so, what do you mean by "best": easiest to support, fastest (on what hardware?), ...?

Comment: Sorry I should have specified. Best = more versatile for other problems. I basically only want to remember one if necessary.

Comment: This is really not answerable, it all depends on the problem(s) you're solving. Without knowing the specifics, this is a too broad question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following for a single line code. I have changed the year values here:

```
data
       year Emissions
114470 1999      7.38
114472 1999      2.78
114477 1998     11.76
114479 1997      3.50
114481 1998      1.32
114486 1997      5.58

df3 = aggregate(Emissions~year, data, sum)
df3
  year Emissions
1 1997      9.08
2 1998     13.08
3 1999     10.16
```

For large data, data.table can be used:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dd)[,list(pollution=sum(Emissions)),by=year]
   year pollution
1: 1999     10.16
2: 1998     13.08
3: 1997      9.08
```

Comment: Thank you! If there was another column (say "type" that was a categorical with 2 factors), could I use aggregate as well to see emissions for each year AND type? I currently do this with melt and cast..

Comment: Try aggregate(Emissions~year+type, data, sum)

Comment: That is so much easier - thanks!